# How do I log just the message content of channel with Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been looking all over and every answer I find doesn't seem to work. Currently, I have:

```
@client.command()
async def history(ctx):
    with open("file.txt", "w") as file:
        async for message in ctx.history(limit=1000):
            file.write(str(message.content + "\n"))

    with open("file.txt", "rb") as file:
        await ctx.send("Your file is:", file=discord.File(file, "transcript.txt"))
    await ctx.send("Done!")
```

All I would like to do is get the message content and author, add that to a file, and give the user that file. If you can help me out, that would be awesome!

### Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method using a dependency called `chat-exporter`. It will give you a very organized HTML file

[image: Example]

```
pip install chat-exporter
```

After installing use it like this.

```py
import chat_exporter

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    chat_exporter.init_exporter(bot) # to get the info if the user left the guild


@bot.command()
async def history(ctx):
    await chat_exporter.export(ctx)
```

[`GitHub`](https://github.com/mahtoid/DiscordChatExporterPy)